# displaying first 20 letter of a value of an associative array in foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, associative-array

i am using codeigniter library, and am stuck in a matter. first here's my array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_name] => some data
        [product_slug] => some data
        [price] => some Data...
        [sell_price] => 2000.00

    )

    [1] => Array (
        [product_name] => some data
        [product_slug] => some data
        [price] => some Data...
        [sell_price] => 2000.00
    )
)
```

now here's my code in controller:

```
$this->load->model('product_model');
$data['product']=$this->product_model->get_product();
$this->load->view('show_product',$data);
```

and heres my model codes

```
function get_product()
{
  return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM dt_product")->result_array();
}
```

and ultimately my view code

```
<div class="featured_right_gallery_bellow">
                    <ul class="product_list">
                                        <?php foreach($product as $product)
                                        {?>
                    <li>
                    <div class="pro_name"><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    }?>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

now my question is that, i want to jst show the first 20 letters of the product_name....but here the full name is being shown...

i know i can write a mysql code like `SELECT LEFT(product_name,20),sell_price,price FROM dt_product`... but i dont want to do that, because the table contains nearly 20 attributes, and i have to change the query multiple times.... all i want is to someone point me out to the solution of how to display the first 20 letter of the product_name using the offset concept,

i tried echoing $product['product_name'][20], but withing foreach loop, its throwing an error of undefined index..

Comment: changing the query is the best option. The php approach would be to  use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). If there is mark-up in the name, you could break it doing this

Comment: @Dagon is changing a query any better than use a mere `substr()`? :) Anyway this is a view's matter, so it should stay in the view.

Comment: thanx a lot, it didnt came to my mind buddy... but what if i want it to be done using associative array concept...bcoz for some purpose i need it in future

Comment: for this time, i am using it in view so i am using substr concept, but what if i want it to be applied as per associative indexing way???

Comment: @moonwave99 there can  significant performance advantages, especially if the retuned string is long, and or stored\parsed

Comment: @Dagon I agree, it can be faster to let the DB do the parsing, but the main reason to do it in the view is because of code maintainability. If you will always want to chop the product name down to 20 characters, do it in the query, but doing it in the view means you can reuse your query, etc. It just depends how much flexibility you want, and how lazy you want to be with your codebase.

Comment: CI also has the function word_limiter() even if it doesnt cut at exactly 20 chars output ir rendered nicer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="pro_name"><?php echo substr($product['product_name'], 0, 20);?></div>
```

Read up on function `substr()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Edit:

If you want to do the edit directly in your array (which I don't think is necessary):

Assuming `$array` is the array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_name] => some data
        [product_slug] => some data
        [price] => some Data...
        [sell_price] => 2000.00

    )

    [1] => Array (
        [product_name] => some data
        [product_slug] => some data
        [price] => some Data...
        [sell_price] => 2000.00
    )
)
```

Then do this:

```
// Iterating through each of the elements of the array.
// $productArray gets loaded as each inner array value.
foreach ($array as $key => $productArray) {
    // The value of $array[$key] is the current inner array.
    // The substr() just gets the value of the product_name key and returns the first 20 characters.
    // To load the modified value, set $array[$key]['product_name'] to the modified value.
    $array[$key]['product_name'] = substr($productArray['product_name'], 0, 20);
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot, it didnt came to my mind buddy... but what if i want it to be done using associative array concept

Comment: @sazet_rey Check my edits for doing the string modification inside the array directly, although it seems like in this case, modifying the number of characters displayed makes the most sense in your view template rather than hijacking the value in the array.